# C++: Forwarding the sum of parameter pack and a std::tuple/array

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, forwarding

I want to implement something like the following member function (method), which is supposed to *increase* each argument by some summand (addend) corresponding to the argument *index* and forward it to another variadic-template function:

```
template<typename... Int> // a bunch of integral types (e.g. int, size_t, char)
void ForwardToFuncIncreased(Int... ints) {
   static_assert(sizeof...(Ints) == std::tuple_size<decltype(summands_)>::value,
                 "Incorrect number of integral types provided");

   Func( (ints + std::get<PARAM_INDEX(ints)>(summands_))... ); // failed attempt
}
```

where `summands_` is a member variable of type `std::tuple` or `std::array` (you can assume either). The basic requirement is that it should have no runtime overhead compared to:

```
Func(int0 + std::get<0>(summands_), int1 + std::get<1>(summands_), ...);
```

(Imagine I overload the function for up to `N` template parameters).

If it is not possible to do it without *necessary* runtime overhead, I am willing to go with certain modifications (esp. in the way of storing additional stuff in my class or modifying the type).

Note: My intention is not to extract the template argument indexes, but hopefully to achieve what I need without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++14, you'll be able to do the following, very similar to your original attempt:

```
template<typename... Ns, size_t... Is>
void ForwardToFuncIncreasedImpl(Ns... nums, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    Func( (nums + std::get<Is>(summands_))... );
}

template<typename... Ns>
void ForwardToFuncIncreased(Ns... nums)
{
    ForwardToFuncIncreasedImpl(nums..., std::index_sequence_for<Ns...>());
}
```

In the meantime, you could find or write your own implementation of `index_sequence`.

Or do something like this: First doing `std::make_tuple(ints...)` so that we have two tuples which we want to sum (or a tuple and a `std::array`). Then using the pattern demonstrated by Andrei Alexandrescu in [The Way of the Exploding Tuple](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/The-Way-of-the-Exploding-Tuple) to expand the sum into a parameter pack which is passed to `Func`.

```
template <int N>
struct Pairwise;

template <>
struct Pairwise<0>
{
    template <typename F, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
    static void Sum(F f, T const&, U const&, Args... sums)
    {
        f(sums...);
    }
};

template <int N>
struct Pairwise
{
    template <typename F, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
    static void Sum(F f, T const& a, U const& b, Args... sums)
    {
        Pairwise<N - 1>::Sum(f, a, b, std::get<N - 1>(a) + std::get<N - 1>(b), sums...);
    }
};

template <typename... Ns>
void ForwardToFuncIncreased(Ns... nums)
{
    Pairwise<sizeof...(Ns)>::Sum(Func, std::make_tuple(nums...), summands_);
}
```

It's also possible to do it without the initial `make_tuple`:

```
template <typename... Ns>
struct Pairwise;

template <>
struct Pairwise<>
{
    template <typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
    static void Sum(F f, T const&, Args... sums)
    {
        f(sums...);
    }
};

template <typename N0, typename... Ns>
struct Pairwise<N0, Ns...>
{
    template <typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
    static void Sum(F f, N0 num0, Ns... nums, T const& a, Args&&... sums)
    {
        Pairwise<Ns...>::Sum(f, nums..., a, sums..., num0 + std::get<sizeof...(Args)>(a));
    }
};

template <typename... Ns>
void ForwardToFuncIncreased(Ns... nums)
{
    Pairwise<Ns...>::Sum(Func, nums..., summands_);
}
```